# What does the term "?T@{x:=t}", or a type with a question mark and at sign surrounding it mean in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to write a function which removes the zeros from a list. Here is the first try of my implementation.

```
Require Import Nat.
Require Import List.
Fixpoint shrink (x : list nat) list nat := (* Mistake! Needs a : list nat *)
  match x with
  | nil    => nil
  | h :: t => if h =? 0 then shrink t else (h :: shrink t)
  end.
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error:
In environment
shrink : forall (x : Datatypes.list Datatypes.nat) 
           (list0 : ?T) (nat : ?T0@{list:=list0}),
         Datatypes.list ?T1@{x:=x; list:=list0; x1:=x}
x : list nat
list : ?T
nat : ?T0
h : Datatypes.nat
t : Datatypes.list Datatypes.nat
The term "shrink t" has type
 "forall (list0 : ?T@{x:=t}) (nat : ?T0@{x:=t; list:=list0}),
  Datatypes.list ?T1@{x:=t; list:=list0; x1:=t}"
while it is expected to have type "Datatypes.list ?T1@{x1:=h :: t}".
```

The correct function implementation is this:

```
Fixpoint shrink (x : list nat) : list nat :=
  match x with
  | nil    => nil
  | h :: t => if h =? 0 then shrink t else (h :: shrink t)
  end.
```

But how am I supposed to interpret the error, in particular `(list0 : ?T@{x:=t})`? In particular,

1. Why is it `list0` instead of `list`?
2. What does `?` mean before the `T`?
3. What does the `@{ ... }` mean after the `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first point, this is just a printing thing but essentially local variables names are just hints for Coq and it may not respect them to avoid confusion. Here it's probably because of the `list := list0` we see later.

Letters preceded by `?` are existential variables or evars, used for unification. Here it doesn't know what the type of `list0` should be because you did not give any, but it knows it has to be *something*. So for now it's `?T` and it will try to figure out later what it should be by looking at its uses.

For `nat` it's the same, but it also knows it might depend on some `list` and in this case its value should be `list0` so it does the instantiation `?T0{list:=list0}`. This notation is for substitution in evars.

I invite you to look at the [documentation of evars in the manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/evars.html) to know more.